# c# how to replace an array string "" to "-"

Tags: c#, arrays, string, replace

I have

```
string data = "a,bn,,rf,,";
```

and split into a string array as

```
string []dataArray = data.Split(',',data);
and array become {"a", "bn", "", "", "rf", "", ""};
```

how can i replace the `""` into `"-"`?
any other convenient way?

thanks for the help.

Comment: The LINQ `.Select` method should help you.

Comment: a `for` loop with an `if`?

Answer (score 8):

You can project the split method returned result using [Select()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) and do that:

```
var result = data.Split(',')
                 .Select(d=> d == String.Empty ? "-" : d);
```

this will give you now:

> {"a", "bn", "-", "-", "rf", "-", "-"}

and you can also eliminate those, if you only need non-empty strings using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) like:

```
var result = data.Split(new char[] {','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

which will give you result like:

> {"a", "bn", "rf"}

Comment: do they want `{"a", "bn", "rf"}` or  `{"a", "bn", "-", "-", "rf", "-", "-"}`

Comment: @MattBeldon The second one is exactly what they want.  What do you think they want?

Comment: @juharr I wrote that comment while the answer only had the former, I think OP wants the latter.

Comment: @MattBeldon The answer always had the code that produces the latter.  They just added the results.

Comment: yes Ehsan Sajjad ... thanks, the second {"a", "bn", "-", "-", "rf", "-", "-"} is what i want. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's a really simple straight forward way to handle this.

```
for(int i=0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
{
    if(dataArray[i] == string.Empty)
    {
        dataArray[i] = "-";
    }
}
```

If you want to handle this before the split you can use a regular expression replacement instead.  (I'm only including this as people keep giving incorrect string replacement answers)

```
data = Regex.Replace(data, "(?<=^|,)(?=,|$)", "-");
```

This checks for either the beginning of the string or a comma before an empty string that is followed by either a comma or the end of the string and replaces that empty string with the dash.

Answer (score 1):

It is typically better to change the value of an object before mutating it into the datatype you intend to use, given the chance.

```
    string data = "a,bn,,rf,,";
    string replacementCharacter = "-";
    //if we know we want a hyphen character where a string.Empty would be, do it now.

    data = data.Replace(",,", "," + replacementCharacter + ",").Trim();
    if (data.EndsWith(",")) { data += "-"; }
    if (data.StartsWith(",")) { data = "-" + data; }
```

Then your array will just be how you want it upon mutation, and you won't have to query the array or iterate through it to fix it.

Edit: updated it to adjust for blank last indexes and carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate results and then check whether result is null or empty. If yes then replace it with -.

Comment: First of all, this should be a comment, or an answer if you include an example *which is exactly what [juharr did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49673935/4934172)*. No need to repeat the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension function i wrote earlier to achieve this

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string[] CustomSplit(this string toSplit, char delimiter, string emptyEntities) => 
        toSplit.Split(delimiter).Select(c => c == string.Empty ? emptyEntities : c).ToArray();
}
```

you can use it like

```
var result = "a,bn,,rf,,".CustomSplit(',', "-");
```

Comment: You don't need `string.IsNullOrEmpty` as `Split` will never produce a `null` value in the resulting array.

Comment: only using it for the empty part, simply replace it with c == string.Empty

Answer (score -1):

You can use this Code I hope this will help you.

```
string data = "a,bn,,rf,,";
string[] dataArray = data.Split(',').Select(c => { c = (c == "") ? "-" : c; return c; }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why not just `c => c == "" ? "-" : c`?   Also this is basically Ehsan's answer.

Comment: I did not check his answer.

Answer (score -4):

Without LINQ

```
var result = data.Split(',', data).Replace(String.Empty, "-");
```

Comment: `.Split(',', data)` won't compile

Comment: And `.Split().Replace` also won't compile!

Comment: yep, have to check fist. What a fail (

Comment: What `Replace` method is that?

Comment: I guess he thought `.Split()` returns a string?